# Performance-wise, is it better to use Hadoop over MPI for a typical embarrassingly parallel scenario?

Tags: java, c, performance, hadoop, mpi

I'm new to both, but I want to understand when it's better to use one over the other.

I know that Hadoop only works on embarrassingly parallel tasks (and that MPI is pretty good for almost anything else), but I can't help but notice that developing a massively parallel program with MPI is almost trivial with the `MPI_Bcast` and `MPI_Allreduce` functions.

So can anyone tell me more about the optimal usage scenario for each (Hadoop and MPI)? Is there any time where (performance-wise) I should look to one instead of the other?

Comment: probably not the answer you're looking for - but I would almost certainly look at options which I can implement in a reasonable amount of time, technology I'm familiar with and which has good support (other developers can expand on the technology or answer any queries that you may have) - best of luck

Comment: I agree with @alihaider. For example, if you would like to develop some sort of scientific application, you should definitely stick to MPI, since it's what virtually all research groups with massively parallel applications use.

Comment: `MPI_All*` and "massively parallel program" don't go well together, especially for large values of "massively" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MPI and Hadoop are designed for different purposes. MPI is a relatevly simple communication middleware, suitable for use in tightly coupled stable static systems, e.g. supercomputers or dedicated computing clusters. It tries to be very light and fast on message passing and provides some options to deal with data arrays. Although it supports heterogeneous environments, it does not support failover nor fault tollerance - if one process dies or some compute node fails, this usually brings down the whole MPI job.